# Import from folder ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm studying JS and I have something like this.

```
//all inside folder reducers

//reducer1.js
export default reducer1

//reducer2.js
export default reducer2

//index.js
import reducer1 from './reducer1'
import reducer2 from './reducer2'
//then combine reducer
export default index

//outside folder reducers
import reducer from './reducers'
```

since `./reducers` is just a folder and there is 3 file with 3 export default inside, I don't understand how this could work ? How does it know which export default in the folder will be imported ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Webpack, when you import a folder, the module loader will import the index.js inside the folder. You are exporting index in index.js, so you are importing it when you do `import reducer from './reducers'`. Importing a folder is just a shorthand for `import reducer from reducers/index`. With mean both import statements are equivalent.

To sums up, `import reducer from './reducers'` is the same as `import reducer from reducers/index`.

Comment: Thank you ! so by default if we want it import something from a folder then the file must be named index.js ?

Comment: @Quoc-Hao-Tran. Yes or you need to name the file explicitly. e.g. `import reducer from reducers/myReducer`

Comment: *"With ES6"* Please note that this behavior has nothing to do with ES6/JavaScript. How module identifiers are interpreted depends on the environments *module loader*, or the module bundler that is used. The behavior you are describing is common for NodeJS and webpack.

Comment: No that's not true. Import and export are part of the new ES6 syntax. The most popular ES implementation is JavaScript. JS has is module loader, so you don't need NodeJS or webpack to import or export modules. Webpack will just give you many advantages when loading modules.  http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear. Of course `import` and `export` are part of ES6. I was just saying that the *interpretation of the module identifier* is not part of the specification. That depends on the module loader. And no, ECMAScript, the language, does not include a module loader definition. The fact that referencing a folder imports the `index.js` is a convention that comes from CommonJS (or Node, not sure) that is described here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together, and which is followed by most loaders. Again, it is not part of the language itself.

Comment: [This is all the spec has to say about interpreting module identifiers]( https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule): *"HostResolveImportedModule is an implementation defined abstract operation that provides the concrete Module Record subclass instance that corresponds to the ModuleSpecifier String, specifier, occurring within the context of the module represented by the Module Record referencingModule."*

Comment: True, importing from a folder is not something from ES6. I updated my answer to avoid more confusion. I don't want to start a debate here, but ECMAScript is not a language and ECMAScript does include a module loader definition, but nothing about loading index.js when loading a folder.